# Planar PCB inductor coil simulation

Tags: pcb, inductor, simulation, electromagnetism, coil

I am working on a planar PCB coil with a complicated shape (not the traditional circular/rectangular spirals.) It is essentially an inductor made out of PCB traces. I want to figure out the inductance of this shape.

Is there any software that I can use to import a shape, specify its thickness and then determine its inductance?

Some of my friends have suggested Ansys or OpenFOAM.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't listen to your friends?

Comment: depends on the accuracy you want. If within a factor of 2 or 3, then approximate your coil into a regular coil by keeping the turns the same area (not perimeter) and using one of the many calculators for regular coils on the web. If better than that, then you need to use one of those solvers your friends are familiar with, but you won't get % accuracy until you use a 3D solver and include every cnductor withn a few diameters of the coil.

Comment: Actually, it's worth doing two approximations, one maintaining the area, one maintaining  the perimeter of each turn. These will under and over estimate respectively, and give you an idea of the error you can expect with this method. However, as you mention thickness, it sounds like you expect crazy-accurate results, which you're unlikely to get however you do it.